# Running a Python script through the Terminal that uses CSV as dataset

Tags: python, csv, unix, matplotlib, terminal

I have a python script that imports MatPlotLib and plots stock prices.

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vals = [float(line.split(',')[7]) for line in sys.stdin]

plt.plot(vals)
plt.title('Stock Price Data')
plt.ylabel('Adjusted Closing Price')
plt.xlabel('Trading Day')
plt.show()
```

I want to run this script in the terminal by importing a file named 2015_goog_sorted.csv (which is 2015 Google stock prices, sorted) as the values to be sorted.

I'm on a Mac and using Atom

I'm in the process of learning commands using unix and terminal, but I know there should be a relatively easy way to do this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why not read a whole file in memory and iterate through it

Comment: Probably because I'm like three months into coding and am not sure how I would do this... haha. 

Could you elaborate?

Comment: @be-ns Is `cat 2015_goog_sorted.csv | python your_program.py` what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  1 import csv
  2
  3 with open('test.csv','r') as f:
  4     a = csv.reader(f)
  5     for row in a:
  6         print(row)
```

The output

```
wirelessprv-10-194-17-39:python Bobby$ python3 te.py
['1', '1', '1', '1']
['2', '2', '2', '2']
```

You can do anything with row

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to run the script as-is, you can hardcode the path to the input file:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open('/path/to/2015_goog_sorted.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    vals = [float(row[7]) for row in reader]

plt.plot(vals)
plt.title('Stock Price Data')
plt.ylabel('Adjusted Closing Price')
plt.xlabel('Trading Day')
plt.show()
```

---

if you want to use unix style piping to send in the input you can do the following:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv


reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
vals = [float(row[7]) for row in reader]

plt.plot(vals)
plt.title('Stock Price Data')
plt.ylabel('Adjusted Closing Price')
plt.xlabel('Trading Day')
plt.show()
```